# Bash Iterative approach in place of process substitution not working as expected

Tags: bash

complete bash noob here. Had the following command (1.) and it worked as expected but it seemed a bit naive for what I needed:

1. Essentially generating a wordlist from a messy input file with tab delimiters

```bash
cat users.txt | tee >(cut -f 1 >> cut_out.txt) >(cut -f 2 >> cut_out.txt) >(cut -f 3 >> cut_out.txt)  >(cut -f 4 >> cut_out.txt)
```

Output:

```
W Humphrey  
SummersW  
FoxxR  
noreply  
DaibaN  
PeanutbutterM  
PetersJ  
DaviesJ  
BlaireJ  
GongoH  
MurphyF  
JeffersD  
HorsemanB  
...
```

2. Thought I could cut down on the ridiculous command above with the following

```bash
cat users.txt | for i in {1..4}; do cut -f $i >> cut_out.txt; done
```

Output:

```
HumphreyW
```

The command above only returned a single word from the list and some white-space.

3. The solution. I knew that I could get it working logically by simply looping the entire command instead, this did exactly what I wanted but just wanted to know why the command above (2.) returned an almost empty file?

```bash
for i in {1..4}; do cat users.txt | cut -f $i >> cut_out.txt; done
```

Have a solution, more-so wanted an explanation because I am dumb and still learning about I/O in bash. Cheers.

Comment: I think I would do `cut -f-4 users.txt | tr '\t' '\n'`, if I understand that the code takes first 4 columns and outputs them on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the output is unimportant, and there are only four coumns in the file, simply

```
tr '\t' '\n' <users.txt >cut_out.txt
```

If you only want the first four columns in any order,

```
cut -f1-4 users.txt |
rt '\t' '\n' >cut_out.txt
```

(Thanks to @KamilCuk for raising this in a comment.)

Otherwise your third attempt is basically fine, though you want to avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)  and redirect only once;

```
for i in {1..4}; do
    cut -f "$i" users.txt
done > cut_out.txt
```

This is obviously less efficient than only reading the file once. If the file is small enough to fit into memory, you could write a simple Awk script to read it once and split it up into variables, and then write out these variables in the order you want.

The second attempt is wrong because `cat` only supplies a single instance of the data to the pipe, and the first iteration of the loop consumes it all.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Just a remark**</sup>

```bash
awk -F '[\t]' '{for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) print $i}' users.txt > cut_out.txt
```

Is basically what your `cat ... | tee >(cut ...) ...` does.

Comment: This is just the `tr` solution in disguise. The `tee >(cut)` solution writes the words in each column together.

Comment: @tripleee I tried to emulate OP's original solution for showing that a copy of the input is needed for each line of output. In that sense the `cut | tr` is quite different.